# How can I forecast using a covariate of different length?

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting, arima, predictor

I have a time series of 100 observations, and I want to make forecasts for the next 2 values.

```
time series: Y(t) = Y(1), Y(2), ... Y(100)
forecast: Y(101), Y(102)
```

I have to use an **arima** (2,0,0) model in order to make prediction.

Secondly, a covariate of length 50 may helps to improve accuracy, but it relates only to the last 50 values of the time series.

```
covariate:     X(t) =           X(1), X(2), ... X(50)
time series:   Y(t) = Y(1), ... Y(51), ... Y(100)
```

It means that *X(1)* has influence on *Y(51)*, *X(2)* on *Y(51)*, ... and *X(50)* on *Y(100)*. I have no values of X prior to 1, so I can not take a covariate of length 100 to cover the entire time series.

The main concerns are:

- I don't want to dismiss the covariate, since it improves the accuracy.
- I don't want to start the time series at Y(51) since it reduces the accuracy.
- I don't know how to use covariates of different length.

How can I solve this issue, and make the most precise forecast of all?
Thanks in advance